# Split current Tab into many rows/cells then create a second tab and do the same

Tags: conemu

I am trying to create a complex console split with ConEmu, two tabs with multi row/columns per tab.

Creating the first tab with 3 rows by two columns works fine

```
-cur_console:t:"1" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s1T66Vn -cur_console:t:"1a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s1T50Hn -cur_console:t:"1b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2TVn -cur_console:t:"1c" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2THn -cur_console:t:"1d" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s4THn -cur_console:t:"1e" cmd.exe
```

But everything goes wrong when I create A second tab with cur_console then all the new rows and columns are applied to the first tab

```
-cur_console:t:"2" cmd.exe

-new_console:s1T66Vn -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s1T50Hn -cur_console:t:"2b" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2TVn -cur_console:t:"2c" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s2THn -cur_console:t:"2d" cmd.exe 
-new_console:s4THn -cur_console:t:"2e" cmd.exe
```

Comment: Do you try that from one task? Than numeration should be consistent, like `-new_console:s7T66Vn -cur_console:t:"2a" cmd.exe`. Also, you may try to create tabs/splits manually and use [Active Tabs](https://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsTasks.html) button.

Comment: Thanks @maximus, I needed to script it

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood the grid system on ConEmu. 
so I created a new console.

```
-new_console:t:"Col 0/0"
```

Then I split it into two equal columns **"s50H"**.

```
-new_console:t:"1/0":s50H
```

I finally creates the rows with **"s1"** for the fist column.

```
-new_console:t:"Col 0/3":s1T30V
```

for the second column with **"s2"**

```
-new_console:t:"Col 1/4":s2T20V
```

This it is an example of two columns with 4 by 5 rows.

```
-new_console:t:"Col 0/0"
-new_console:t:"1/0":s50H

-new_console:t:"Col 0/3":s1T30V
-new_console:t:"Col 0/2":s1T30V
-new_console:t:"Col 0/1":s1T40V

-new_console:t:"Col 1/4":s2T20V
-new_console:t:"Col 1/3":s2T30V
-new_console:t:"Col 1/2":s2T30V
-new_console:t:"Col 1/1":s2T30V
```